# Addon-SDK use Ctrl-Enter to fire an action

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

How do I set <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> as a global hotkey for firing an extension action?

I'm using [Add-on SDK](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK) to develop this addon.